# Android Studio и MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица с столбцами 1 2, где в первом столбце есть строки а а а б б с с д и тд, как вывести все данные из второго столбца, где в первом столбце строчка А ?

Как я понимаю , надо взять либо id элемента ListView , либо же Position и потом как-то это обработать

Comment: Плохо понял вопрос. Но если нужен запрос, то вот он: `select 2 from table where 1 = "A"`

Comment: Да, всегда было плохо с составлением вопросов ;c 
Именно то, что нужно, но возвращает 0 строк при проверке этого в программе Db Brower for SQLite.
А как это сделать , но в android studio ?